# Iterating through the keys of a json object in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am getting a JSON response like this:-

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Data found",
  "list": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "First Data"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "Second Data"
    }
  ],
  "total": 3,
  "current_page": "1",
  "error": 0
}
```

In the component file, I am storing the `list` obj like this:-

```
viewPage(page,per_page){  
  this._adminPage.fetchAdminPageData(page, per_page).subscribe(
      data => {
            this.list = data.list;
            this.total_item = data.total;
            this.current_page = data.current_page;
            this.arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(this.list);
            //this.setPage(1);
          },
      err => {
            console.log(err)
          },
      () => {}
    ); 
  this.status = true;       
}
```

Using the `this.arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(this.list);` I am getting the keys of `list`.

When I am printing it in html `{{arrayOfKeys}}`, I am getting data like this `0,1`

I want to iterated through the keys of list[0], and display the name of each key in table header. Something link this:-

```
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th *ngFor='let key of arrayOfKeys'>[here goes the name of the key ie. id/title/etc]</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

That means, if my keys are **id** & **title** then table headers would show **id** and **title**. If my keys are **f_name** & **l_name**, then table headers would show **f_name** and **l_name**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can use `this.arrayOfKeys=Object.keys(list[0]);`

Comment: will there be same no of keys in each array element of `list`?

Comment: It depends upon the API. The API can be modified to send more or less no of keys

Comment: check my answer if this is you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `this.arrayOfKeys=Object.keys(list[0]);` if each array elements have the same no of keys . If you use `Object.keys(list);` it will give you only array indexes. You can check the below code -

```
viewPage(page,per_page){  
  this._adminPage.fetchAdminPageData(page, per_page).subscribe(
      data => {
            this.list = data.list;
            this.total_item = data.total;
            this.current_page = data.current_page;
            this.arrayOfKeys=Object.keys(list[0]); //["id", "title"]
            //this.setPage(1);
          },
      err => {
            console.log(err)
          },
      () => {}
    ); 
  this.status = true;       
}
```

Then use it in the HTML

```
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th *ngFor='let key of arrayOfKeys'>{{key}}</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: This is the exact answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Just let some time go. Can't accept answer before 10 minutes are over

Answer (score 1):

If the keys are the same and present for all objects, you can just get away with:

```
const keys = Object.keys(data.list[0]);
```

If not, you can aggregate the keys of all objects, for example using an itermediate `Set`:

```js
const data = {
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Data found",
  "list": [{
      "id": "1",
      "title": "First Data"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "Second Data"
    }
  ],
  "total": 3,
  "current_page": "1",
  "error": 0
};

const keys = Array.from(data.list.reduce((a, v) => {
  Object.keys(v).forEach(k => a.add(k));
  return a;
}, new Set()));

console.log(keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

Expose `Object.keys()` method from component to your template:

```
public objKeys = Object.keys;
```

So you can iterate over keys:

```
<div *ngFor="let key of objKeys(yourObject)">{{key}}</div>
```

Comment: Explain in detail